# How to properly tag a reissue patent?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just encountered a [question regarding a reissue patent](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/13750/14417), and I haven't found the correct tag syntax to get the patent sidebar to show. I've tried `usre45370` and `usre45370e1`. Google's "Discuss This Patent" links to `usre45370`, so it seems that it would be the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, there's a pretty strict condition for what types of tags queue the sidebar to show up, and I don't think I've ever seen a reissue tag trigger that.

Given that, I think what you picked is a fine precedent for how these should be formatted. The most important part with choosing a tag format, especially for patent numbers here, is making it consistent, and going with what the Discuss this Patent button points to sounds like a good approach to accomplishing that.

If you'd like, you could post a new meta question using the tag [feature-request](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) to ask for tags beginning in "usre" to bring up the sidebar, citing this post or the one you linked to for more context. I'm not sure how high a priority that would be for the developer team, but it doesn't hurt to get something on the books. I imagine this is a pretty straight-forward change, like adding it to a regex.