# Feature Request: Support Reissue Patent tags with patent sidebar

Tags: feature-request, tags

Reissue Patent tags (e.g., `usre45370`) are not recognized by the patent sidebar. Could the code that recognizes patent tags be revised to support this format (`usre\d+`)?

Please also see the following related question for a test case:

[How to properly tag a reissue patent?](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/q/295/14417)